# Minify a script in its own bundle to be picked up for a web worker in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle, minify, web-worker

I am working on an Angular (v6) application and, in a particular component, I want to initialise a web worker via `Worker` by passing a JavaScript file which I want to minify in production.

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {

  constructor() {
    this.worker = new Worker('script.js');
    this.worker.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
      ...
    };
  }

}
```

The `angular.json` of the application is as follows:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "scripts": [
              "src/scripts/worker.script.js",
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The file `src/scripts/worker.script.js` contains a typical Javascript self-invoking anonymous function:

```
(function() {
  ...
}());
```

Now, this solution satisfies me only partially because all the scripts get minified together in `scripts.js`, therefore what I pass to the Worker could be possibly more than what I need to. In particular, if at any point I needed a second `Worker` taking on a second script, my approach would fail. Please consider the following limitations:

- I want the JavaScript file to be minified, therefore I want to avoid to add it to the `assets` section of the `angular.json`
- I cannot refactor the JavaScript file.